# mysql self-refrencing table returning id of parent and count of children

Tags: mysql, parent, self-reference

I have a self referencing table and I want a mysql query that will return only the top most parent (parent = 0) and the number of children belonging to each of those. This is what I have so far, but I know it will not work.

`SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM example where parent_id = id) FROM example WHERE parent_id = 0;`

```
+--------+-----------+
|   id   | parent_id |
+--------+-----------+
|    1   |     0     |
|    2   |     1     |
|    3   |     1     |
|    4   |     0     |
|    5   |     4     |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hope this one help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-in-a-less-number-of-mysql-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT parent_id parent, count( * ) num_children
FROM example
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING parent_id
IN (

SELECT id
FROM `example`
WHERE parent_id =0
)
```

Comment: I changed `HAVING parent_id` to `HAVING parent_id <> 0` and now it works.

Comment: Hmm...seems strange... worked for me perfectly. In my opinion `HAVING parent_id <> 0` is not needed here since it is already fetching the top level parents within the Subquery.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Using the query you gave me returned an empty result, and using it with the change returned what I had wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this should work:

```
SELECT parent_id, count( * ) cnt
FROM example
WHERE parent_id
IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM `example`
   WHERE parent_id =0
)
GROUP BY parent_id
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only provide me with the count of the `id`'s where the `parent_id` is equal to 0?

Comment: Yes sorry, misread your question. Think @Dave Morris has got it spot on anyway.

Comment: Edited mine, but does the same thing as @Dave Morris's answer.

Comment: You're code didn't work, but I was able to give it a minor tweak and now it's working here is the code.

`SELECT parent_id, count( * ) cnt
FROM form_part
WHERE parent_id <> 0
IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM form_part
   WHERE parent_id =0
)
GROUP BY parent_id`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers provided by Dave Morris and Tomgrohl I was able to get it to work. Here is the MySQL I used.

```
SELECT parent_id parent, count( * ) num_children
FROM example
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING parent_id <> 0
IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM `example`
    WHERE parent_id = 0
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to prefix columns with table alias

SELECT id, (SELECT COUNT(inner.id) FROM example inner where inner.parent_id = outer.id) FROM example outer WHERE parent_id = 0;